# Android: Problem when drawing the same bitmap over and over on canvas

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

So I have a bitmap that I have loaded from a resource file (an PNG image):

```
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wave);
```

If I draw this bitmap only once using `canvas.drawBitmap(...);` then there is no problem. However, If I draw that very same bitmap multiple times, then the picture keeps flashing back and forth, not steady like before.

I suspected that I cannot use the same bitmap more than once so I tried to load the image into a new bitmap every time when I want to draw the same picture, but it does not help, the behavior still persists.

The program is complicated, but basically, I want to draw a ocean wave. I have a image of a small wave. To make the effect of the wave moving from the left edge of the screen to the right edge. I keep track of the position of the left edge of the bitmap.

```
// The ocean.
private ArrayList<Wave> waves;

            // Draw the waves and update their positions.
    for (int i = 0; i < this.waves.size(); i++)
    {
        Wave wave = this.waves.get(i);

        // Go through each of the sub-waves of this current wave.
        for (int j = 0; j < wave.getSubWaveEdges().size(); j++)
        {
            // Get the sub wave.
            final float subWaveEdge = wave.getSubWaveEdges().get(j);

            canvas.drawBitmap( wave.getSubWave(j), subWaveEdge, 40, brush);

            wave.setSubWaveEdge(j, subWaveEdge + (float) 0.5);
        }

        // Update this current wave.
        wave.update();

        // If the wave has passed the left edge of the screen then add a new sub-wave.
        if (wave.getFarthestEdge() >= 0)
            wave.addSubWaveEdges(wave.getFarthestEdge() - this.getWidth());
    }
```

If the left edge of a bitmap is inside the screen then I create a new bitmap from the same image file and draw. Here is the class Wave:

```
    private class Wave
{
    private Bitmap wave;
    private float farthestEdge;
    private ArrayList<Float> subWaveEdges;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> subWaves;

    public Wave(Bitmap wave)
    {   
        this.wave = wave;

        this.farthestEdge = 0;

        this.subWaveEdges = new ArrayList<Float>();

        this.subWaves = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    }

    public Bitmap getWave ()
    { return this.wave; }

    public void setWave (Bitmap wave)
    { this.wave = wave; }

    public float getFarthestEdge ()
    { return this.farthestEdge; }

    public void setFarthestEdge (final float furthestEdge)
    { this.farthestEdge = furthestEdge; }

    public ArrayList<Float> getSubWaveEdges ()
    { return subWaveEdges; }

    public void setSubWaveEdge (final int index, final float value)
    {
        this.subWaveEdges.remove(index);

        this.subWaveEdges.add(value);
    }

    public void addSubWaveEdges (final float edge)
    {
        this.subWaveEdges.add(edge);

        Bitmap newSubWave = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wave);

        newSubWave = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(newSubWave, MasterView.this.getWidth(), newSubWave.getHeight(), true);

        this.subWaves.add(newSubWave);
    }

    public Bitmap getSubWave(final int index)
    { return this.subWaves.get(index); }

    public void update ()
    {

        // Check to see if there is any sub-wave going outside of the screen.
        // If there is then remove that wave.
        for (int index = 0; index < this.subWaveEdges.size(); index++)
            if (this.subWaveEdges.get(index) > MasterView.this.getWidth())
            {
                this.subWaveEdges.remove(index);

                this.subWaves.remove(index);
            }

        // Set the farthest edge to the other side of the screen.
        this.farthestEdge = MasterView.this.getWidth();

        // Get the farthest edge of the wave.
        for (int index = 0; index < this.subWaveEdges.size(); index++)
            if (this.subWaveEdges.get(index) < this.farthestEdge)
                this.farthestEdge = this.subWaveEdges.get(index);
    }
}
```

Another suspicion that I have is that may be when I create two bitmaps from the same resource file, the pixels of the image are divided among two bitmaps, meaning that each bitmap only gets part of the pixels, not all. I am suspecting this because when the bitmaps are drawn, the parts where they overlaps are drawn steadily, no flashing.

Anyone has stumbled upon this problem and know how to fix?

Thanks,

Comment: I just did, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viktor Lannér, Thank you for helping, but I don't think that's the problem. I understand it is hard to read my codes since it is only a small piece of the big program.

However, I found the problem: This is not mentioned in my original question, but in order to simulate the two waves moving after one another, I have to draw the next wave as soon as the first wave enters the screen. However, each wave is longer than the width of the screen. Therefore, I have to draw the next wave from "outside" the screen if you know what I mean. It means that the next wave is drawn from a negative x-coordinate from outside the screen:

```
    // If the wave has passed the left edge of the screen then add a new sub-wave.
    if (wave.getFarthestEdge() >= 0)
        wave.addSubWaveEdges(wave.getFarthestEdge() - this.getWidth());
```

And I found out that it does not like this. This is what causes the flashing back and forth.

In order to fix this, instead of drawing the next wave from outside the screen, I use this method:

```
     canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect source, Rect destination, Paint paint)
```

This method allows you to specify a rectangular region on the bitmap to be drawn to the screen and a rectangular region on the screen where that part of the bitmap will be drawn over. I use this method to draw the next wave. As the next wave moves into the screen, I change the "source" and "destination" appropriately to draw parts of the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say that I had an issue where the images on my canvas were flashing back and forth, or, flashing between black and my first frame until I made a movement, almost as if the canvas was rapidly switching between its current and last image.

This might have had something to do with your situation, and to fix it I found out that it was because I was locking the canvas every frame, even when I had nothing to draw.  For whatever reason, that lock, I think, created this situation.

I got around it by doing something like this:

```
if (needToRedraw == true) {
      canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
      ... logic to eventually draw on that canvas ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `canvas.drawBitmap(...)` call; try to use `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)` to clear the `Canvas` from previous drawings.

Sample code:

```
// Stuff.
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawBitmap(wave.getSubWave(j), subWaveEdge, 40, brush);
// Stuff.
```